# How to write php returns json format according to the key?

Tags: php, json, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I use XAMPP to create local networks and write php file to return the data in the database as json. This is my code:

```
 <?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "landslide";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

function myexample {
    $mysqli = "SELECT id, temp, acc, moisture, battery, time FROM devices";
    $result = $conn->query($mysqli);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $response["main"] =array();
            $response["parameters"]= array();
            $main = array();
            $main["id"]=$row["id"];
            array_push($response["main"],$main);

            $parameter = array();
            $parameter["temp"] = $row["temp"];
            $parameter["acc"] = $row["acc"];
            $parameter["moisture"] = $row["moisture"];
            $parameter["battery"] = $row["battery"];
            $parameter["time"] = $row["time"];
            array_push($response["parameters"],$parameter);

        }
            // echoing JSON response
          $result_response =  echo json_encode($response);
          return $result_response;


        }
} // end of my example function 
?>
```

now when you call this function  you will get json_encode format

now parse it by using

```
$res = JSON.parse($result_response);
```

now

```
$moisture = $res['moisture'];
```

My local link: http://127.0.0.1/landslide/currentdata.php .

Now, I want to write one php file returns json format according to the "key"(here i want key is id). As of Openweather api address below, key is cities (example London). http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk

So, how to i return json format by php according to key? Please help me! (My expression was not good, sorry about that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are returning the `json_encode($response);`

You need to parse it to get in like an object and access it you can achieive it like in one variable.

```
$result = JSON.parse($response);
```

and access this `$result array` like if you want to access `moisture`

then `$moisture = $result['moisture'];` like so on...

Comment: That means i repaced > echo json_encode($response); by >$result = JSON.parse($response);and add > $moisture = $result['moisture']; below?

Comment: try to put all your code in one function and return like this $result_response = json_encode($response); Then you can parse and get it like $moisture = $result['moisture'];

Comment: i still do not quite understand, Can you edit my code above in your way? Thank you very much and sorry for my lack of knowledge